# Quebra de página dinâmica quando imprimir (na <table>)

Tags: css, impressão

Em uma tela de orçamento, exibo os produtos cadastrados dentro de um Foreach em uma tabela (cada produto), então em alguns casos, na hora da impressão da página a tabela fica quebrada e acaba ficando muito feio na impressão. Testei em meu CSS o seguinte:

```
@media print {
    table { 
        page-break-after: always; 
    }
}
```

Porém ele quebra a pagina SEMPRE toda vez que tiver tabela mas o que eu preciso é quebrar dinamicamente, somente quando houver uma quebra de página. Também testei com 'auto' ao invés de 'always' e não obtive êxito.

Como posso fazer a quebra somente quando a *Table* for quebrar na tela de impressão?

EDIT: Procurei em diversos lugares e até agora não consegui resolver a quebra de página dinâmica, ou seja, somente quebrar a pagina quando a tabela vier quebrada.

Uma dúvida cruel, por quê o 'auto' não funciona? Incompatibilidade de navegador? (chrome v36)

Comment: Já tentou usar `auto` em vez de `always`? A propósito, você só quer que troque de página se a tabela **inteira** não cabe nela, certo? Em vez de, digamos, quebrar nas linhas da tabela em vez disso (caso em que o `page-break-after` se aplicaria ao `tr` em vez do `table`). P.S. [Pergunta relacionada (no SOen)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17761646/520779)

Comment: @mgibsonbr tentei aplicar no _tr_ e não funcionou. Pesquisei na SOen no link que indicou e tentei algumas possíveis soluções e continuo no zero.

Answer (score 1):

Existem textos nos relatórios fora das tabelas? Ou são somente tabelas que você quer imprimir? Eu tenho um exemplo aqui somente com tabela de várias páginas, que funcionou perfeitamente, utilizando apenas os controles de css citados acima.

```
table { page-break-inside:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

Lembrando que a tabela deve estar estruturada corretamente com todas as tags html de acordo.

Referências:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

icul8r.

Comment: fora da tabela não, dá uma olhada como fica quando vou imprimir

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/528x523q90/539/cPdtxE.png

Tentei utilizar o que me passou mas não deu certo. A estrutura do código da tabela aparentemente está correta.

Comment: Cara, acabei de testar com 'avoid' ao invés de 'auto' e FUNCIONOU!

   `table { page-break-inside:avoid }`

Comment: opa, boa notícia, solução registrada então!

Answer (score 1):

Comigo também funcionou usando o `avoid`.

Bastou colocar a regra CSS já citada acima.

```
@media print{
    table{ page-break-inside:avoid; }
}
```